# Culture Names used by other cultures

Tags: .net, globalization

Most of probably know that we can call against the CultureInfo's static GetCultures method to retrieve a collection of Cultures. Each culture will have it's own name - to take an example, "English/United States"...

My question is, is it possible to see how other cultures name that specific culture? The French will have a one name for it, the Germans another and so on and so forth...

What I'm therefore looking to do is something like this:

```
public string GetNameUsingCulture(CultureInfo selectedCulture, CultureInfo selectedLanguageCulture)
{
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

`CultureInfo` has three "displays":

- DisplayName: based on the .NET "language" installed (in Italian on my pc)
- NativeName: localized in the language of the Culture (so for the culture fr it would be in french)
- EnglishName: always in english

So on my pc (with Italian .NET), for `new CultureInfo("fr")` I have

- DisplaName: Francese
- NativeName: français
- EnglishName: French

Comment: That "DisplayName" gave me hope... I thought I could perhaps reset the thread's cuture / ui culture and get an answer that way... Sadly that doesn't seem to work either...